# Is it possible to Server Side Render a Wordpress theme built in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming

does anyone know or have tried if its possible to make my Wordpress theme built in ReactJS render in the server side for SEO purposes? Thanks

I've research and read this (https://github.com/humanmade/react-wp-ssr) and it seems its using create react app approach which is ditch by react and also its pretty old and was thinking if there's a better or newer approach to this.

Currently, I am using wp-scripts to build my react js files in wordpress.